# Bootstrap : input-group and select height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Why input-group with `select` don't have simular render of `input` ?

I want `select` height relative of `input-group`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
      <i class="fa fa-3x fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="input-group">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option>
      Option 1
    </option>
  </select>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
      <i class="fa fa-3x fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Thanks you very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just edit one line in your form stylesheet as below

```css
select.form-control:not([size]):not([multiple]) {
    height: auto!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
      <i class="fa fa-3x fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="input-group">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option>
      Option 1
    </option>
  </select>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
      <i class="fa fa-3x fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```